# Unable to save text to mysql database and also how to comment quote reply

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

I have this code where i write comment in a textarea field and select a picture and sumbit to mysqli database through php, but the problem im having is when i only select a picture to upload or when i write a comment/texts in the textarea and select a picture to upload it works but then when i only write comment/texts in the textarea field and submit it doesn't work.
    And also i want to create a comment reply "quote" , like to click reply on a comment then quote and reply the comment.

```
        // My compose form

        <form method="post" action="process.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          <textarea class="text-area" cols="75" name="comment" type="text" rows="5" placeholder="write message"></textarea><br>
          <input type='file' style="width:257px" name='fileToUpload' ><br>
          <input class="submitButton" type='submit' value='Send'>
        </form>





        // My process.php code

        <?php

        // start username session
        session_start();

        //connect to database
        require_once ("dtb.php");

        $commentSenderName = $_SESSION['username'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']) : "";

        //Directory where to upload file
        $name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
        $target_dir = "upload/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

        //Select file type
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        //Valid file extensions
        $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif","NULL");

        //Check extension
        if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

        //Upload file
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],$target_dir.$name);

        //Insert data into tables
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tblcomment(comment,comment_sender_name,date,image) VALUES ('". $comment . "','" . $commentSenderName . "','" . $date . "','".$name."')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (! $result) {
            $result = mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        echo "<p style='padding-left:22px;padding-top:10px;font-family:verdana;font-size:20px'> Post entered... </p>";
                       header("Refresh: 3; url=mysite.com");

        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>



        // This is the code that fetches and display data from mysql database

        $sql = "SELECT comment_sender_name,date,comment,image FROM tblcomment";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //output data of each row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $name = $row['comment_sender_name'];
                $time = $row['date'];
                $msg = $row['comment'];
                $img = $row['image'];
                $now = array("<span><b style='font-size:25px'> $name </b></span>","<span style='font-size:14px;color:#474747;padding-left:40px;'><i>$time</i></span>");
                $message = "<p style='color:#232323;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold'> $msg </p>";
                $image_src = "<a href='#'><img src='upload/$img' style='width:550px;height:320px;border-radius:5px'></img></a>";
                echo  '<table border="0" style="padding-left:25px;box-sizing;height:450px;width:400px;">
                       <tr>
                       <td>' .$now[0] .$now[1] .$message .$image_src. "<br/><br/><br/><br/>". '</td>
                       </tr>';

            }
        } else {
            echo "<p style='padding-left:22px'> 0 results </p>";
        }
          //Free result set
          mysqli_free_result($result);


        ?>
```

Im not getting any kind of error.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: You also have a lot of cross site scripting issues here...

Comment: *"Im not getting any kind of error."* - I don't see error reporting.

Comment: And `<textarea>` has no "type".

Comment: i did not get any error reported and also there's no error in my web server's log files

Comment: @Ch3v, depending on what out of the box webserver you used, you may need to increase error_reporting and possibly adjust display_errors/log_errors.  There is more info here: https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/360020711631/how-to-enable-php-error-logging-via-php.ini

Comment: im using a web hosting provider

Comment: Shared hosting still exits?

Comment: yes it still exists lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from my comment above with the many, many vulnerabilities in your code, the issue looks like you assume you always have a $_FILES.  If you didn't upload a file, `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];` is not going to exist.  Check for it with `if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {` and act on that information appropriately.  You probably did get an error, or more specifically a warning, but it is in your web servers log file.

Comment: @aynber added the solution for the SQL injection.  Cross Site Scripting is a little more difficult.  Take a read though https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know

Comment: your solution is not clear and doesn't solve my problem

Comment: you have my code above show me where to add if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {

Comment: I will give you a hint, check that `$_FILES` contains `'fileToUpload'` before using `$_FILES['fileToUpload']`.

Comment: There is no way anyone here can "fix it" for you as we don't have the reset of the website and database.  For example, `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: Is there a way i can contact you directly off here so i can share the rest of the website with you?